# Osticket and Office365 - SMTP authentication failure

Tags: office365, osticket

I am trying to configure `OsTicket` with `Office365`.

IMAP is working correctly but I have problem with configuration of SMTP.

My configuration and error is as follows:
[image: Configuration]

I have tried also another configuration suggested on OsTicket forum but it did not work either:
[image: Configuration and error 2]

I have looked threw OsTicket forum but did not find any reliable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have patched osTicket's mail class at /include/pear/Net/SMTP.php changing the line:

```
$this->_socket_options =$socket_options;
```

to

```
$this->_socket_options = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false));
```